# Determining if function is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Question:

Let $\\f: \ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ via $ f(x) = (x+2, x-3)$. Is $f$ injective? Is $f$ surjective?

I was able to prove that $f$ is injective. However, I am not quite sure if $f$ is surjective. If it is surjective could someone please tell me how to prove that. If not, could someone provide a counter example.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Let $y=f(x)=( y_1 , y_2 ),$ notice that $y_1-y_2=5$

Now consider point $(6,0)$, does it have a preimage?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need to show that for any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=(a,b)$. Since $f(x)=(x+2, x-3)$ then $a=x+2$ and $b=x-3$. In particular $x=a-2$ and $x=b+3$ and therefore $a-2=b+3$ and finally $a=b+5$. So that's the constraint on $(a,b)$ in order for it to be in the image of $f$. Finding a counterexample is easy now, e.g. $(a,b)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to understand the intuition behind surjectivity :

A fonction is surjective if it at least fully "fills" the "end space" (if someone knows the real term feel free to comment) here $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

But since it take $x$ values in $\mathbb{R}$, it won't be able to "fill" $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Here your fonction $f(x) = (x+2, x-3)$ will map $x$ to a point on the line of equation $y=x-5$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, so everything outside of that line would not be reached, hence it is not surjective.

Another thing you should keep in mind, for a function to be bijective (injective and surjective) the starting space and ending space need to be the same dimension, so if $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is injective it can't be surjective since $\dim(\mathbb{R}) \ne \dim(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$.

I hope those quick tips helped you get a better understanding of those notions.

Comment: What? Of course there can be a surjective function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. Obviously they have the same cardinality. But even continuous functions exist, e.g. space filling curves. The algebraic dimension is **completely** irrelevant here.

Comment: I'm talking intuition here. Indeed you can craft exotic functions but for finite set and most infinite domain function, the intuition holds.